# ggplot2 z clipping: remove unnecessary points in overlapping stacks

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following example of plotting 100 overlapping points:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100)), aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_point(size=100) +
    xlim(-10, 10) +
    ylim(-10, 10)
```

[image]

I now want to save the image as vector graphics, e.g. in PDF. This is not a problem with the above example, but once I've got over a million points (e.g. from a volcano plot), the file size can exceed 100 MB for one page and it takes ages to display or edit.

In the above example the same shape could could still be represented by either

- converting the points to a shape outline, or
- keeping a couple of points and discarding the rest.

Is there any way (or preferably tool that already does this) to remove points from a plot that will never be visible? (ideally supporting transparency)

The best approach I have heard so far is to round the position of the dots and remove grid points that have > N points, then use the original positions of the remaining ones. Is there anything better?

Note that this should work with an **arbitrary structure** of points, and only remove those that are not visible.

Comment: Could you use geom_tile() or geom_raster() instead? It is essentially a 3D histogram, so it would summarize the data for each cell, which you can make as small as you like with the "breaks" argument. If this is useful, it will also show how many points were in each cell (i.e. how much overlap there is), but you could set the fill manually to black and use a variable that doesn't change (or make up a dummy column of all ones) if it needs to look like your example. [link] (http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_tile.html)

Comment: Not really. I want to keep the plot as-is, but drop points that will never be visible to the user.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something with the convex hull, like this, filling in the polygon that makes up the convex hull:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
idx <- chull(df)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point(size = 100,color="darkgrey") +
    geom_polygon(data=df[idx,],color="blue") +
    geom_point(size = 1, color = "red", size = 2) +
    xlim(-10, 10) +
    ylim(-10, 10)
```

yielding:

[image]

(Note that I pulled this chull-idea out of Hadley's "Extending ggplot2" guide https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html.)

In your case you would drop the `geom_point` calls and set transparency on the `geom_polygon`. Also not sure how fast `chull` is for millions of points, though it will clearly be faster than plotting them all.

And I am not really sure what you are after. If you really want the 100 pixel radius, they you could probably just do it for the ones on the complex hull, plus fill in the middle with `geom_polygon`.

So using this code:

```
ggplot(df[idx,], aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point(size = 100, color = "black") +
    geom_polygon(fill = "black") +
    xlim(-10, 10) +
    ylim(-10, 10)
```

to make this:
[image]

Comment: I like the idea of the convex hull. The problem with it is, in combination with `geom_point`, that if I've got points in a line A-B-C, it might drop B even though for larger distances the point B would add to the outline of A-B-C.

Comment: You could handle that in a post-processing step though by adding points.

Comment: But how would I select with ones to add? Distance to the line? Calculating another convex hull with the initial points removed? (that might actually work reasonably well)

Comment: It would also break down if you change e.g. `size=1` in the above example. - Then it wouldn't take care of the overlap at all anymore.

Comment: Yeah, been thinking about it. It is a hard problem, because the answer is not necessarily convex really. Adding points like I suggested only makes sense in the convex case. This is more of a heuristic to get a close approximation. But I bet this technique will get you pretty close most of the time.

Comment: Just upvoted. It is a great question. It needs a bounty really.